# My Php page is only rendering in half and full in mobile devices

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, browser, rendering

I recently found this problem on my cleints website

Actually the problem is very interesting

when i open any page of the [website](https://0123movieshd.org/movie.php?name=watch-the-darkest-minds-full-movie-123movieshd-17797)

I only get half of the page through my laptop , no scroll bar and nothing

and when i see the source code its exactly correct but not rendering

and one more thing this website is working perfect in mobile devices

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Okay. And what are we expected to do now? Do you have any more precise specs than "my laptop"? What resolution? What browser version? (I assume its GC due to the tag). Have you tried reproducing the issue in dev tools?

Comment: why are all your meta tags in the body and not the head?

Answer (score -1):

verify your style file, maybe you are hide a part for large device